# Search.php display results differently based on post type

Tags: search

I'm trying to work on my search.php template.  I'd like to display results differently based on their post type.  I have Pages, Posts and Machines (a custom post type)

Here's an example of the results page at the moment: 
http://dev.digitalgroupmedia.com/fortron/?s=fortron&search-submit=Submit+Query
The first result is a post, the others are Machines

Pages and Posts can be displayed with a simple hyperlinked title, but I'd like the machines to have the format they currently have.

My php isn't amazing and is usually cobbled together through random trial and error.  I know there needs to be some sort if/else statement template to check the post type and then display them based on that, but I'm struggling.  Any help would be really appreciated.  Here's my code thus far:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

## Search Results for ''

```
        <?php $i = 1;?>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <div class="products row-fluid clearfix">

            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <div class="span3 machine">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php
                        $machineImage = types_render_field( "machine-image", array( "alt" => "Fortron Machine Tools", "title" => "Fortron Machine Tools", "width" => "184", "height" => "162", "align" => "center", "resize" => "pad", "padding_color" => "transparent", 'index' => 0 ) );
                            if ($machineImage){
                                echo $machineImage;
                            };
                    ?>
                    </a>
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                </div>    

            <?php if($i % 4 == 0) {echo '</div><!-- end machines row fluid --><div class="row-fluid clearfix">';} ?>
            <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
            </div><!-- end products row fluid -->

            <?php else : ?>

            <strong>Sorry, nothing found.</strong>

        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- span8 end -->
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
</div><!-- container end -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this inside your loop

```
if ( 'machine' == get_post_type() ){
           //code for machine post types
}elseif ( 'post' == get_post_type()){
           //code for posts
}elseif ( 'page' == get_post_type()){
           // code for pages
}
else{
           //code for anything else
}
```